# count occurrence of a words in a csv file in python using nltk

Tags: python, nltk

I tried to count the number of occurrence of the word "the" in a .csv file, but when I run 
the following code, it returns 0.  (test.csv is located [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AvcSw7LvweISdHFPNGpwS3lrbzQ4dHVtZXBaeW5fNkE&usp=sharing))

I just search the first column of this file.

```
import csv
import nltk

tweet = []

for t in csv.DictReader(open('test.csv'), delimiter=','):
    tweet.append(t['text'])

tweet_text = nltk.Text(tweet)
print tweet_text.count("the")
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split `text` field into words using [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.split), and use [`list.extend`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#mutable-sequence-types) accordingly.   And make lowercase unless you only want lowercase `the`.

```
>>> nltk.Text(['the world The words']).count('the')
0
>>> nltk.Text(['the', 'world', 'The', 'words']).count('the')
1
```

Complete code:

```
import csv
import nltk

tweet = []

for t in csv.DictReader(open('test.csv'), delimiter=','):
    tweet.extend(t['text'].lower().split()) # <-----------

tweet_text = nltk.Text(tweet)
print tweet_text.count('the')
```